# Windows SDK vs Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

We're currently facing some [clashes between VS and Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), and it occured to me that there's something fundamental I don't understand:
Why does MS publish two separate lines of development tools for windows??   I realize WinSDK is free, and does not include an IDE - but why maintain two separate sets of headers and libs?   Shouldn't WinSDK in principle be a subset of a VS release?

Comment: There have been several Windows SDK releases/version over time. Some of them are complimentary with Visual Studio, other stand alone. Visual Studio typically uses one specific version among installed Windows SDKs.

Comment: The link you posted refers to a different scenario altogether. It highlights some of the difficulties when moving an external SDK (DirectX) into the core Windows SDK.

Comment: As others have pointed out, MSVS and the Windows SDK are essentially two different products.  Stuff like the DirectX SDK, Silverlight SDK and Device Driver Kits are yet again different products.  Q: What's the actual problem you're experiencing?  Maybe it isn't a "conflict" at all?

Comment: The link (and the actual problem) are this scenrio exactly, since we make extensive use of d3dx types. Quoting the link:
"... D3DX is not considered the canonical API for using Direct3D in Windows 8 and later and therefore isn't included with the corresponding Windows SDK. Investigate alternate solutions for working with the Direct3D API. For legacy projects, such as the Windows 7 (and earlier) DirectX SDK samples, the following steps are necessarry... "
I'd say it's a bit early to consider windows 7 legacy, but oh well.

I wonder why all the downvotes. Any downvoter cares to explain?

Comment: I suppose it's just not really clear what you're asking, Ofek. You haven't explicitly stated what your problem is. And if your problem is roughly what the previous comment describes you already posted a link to the solution.

Comment: I have come to this question because I am not sure if `dumpbin` is part of the Windows SDK (which I would actually strongly assume) or part of Visual Studio (which seems to actually be the case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows supports programs written in any language or IDE.  To that end, Microsoft publishes a canonical set of headers, libraries, tools, and samples for that specific build of Windows.

For example, there are separate SDKs for Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.  Each SDK has its own set of headers, although in practice each new SDK is a superset of the last.

These headers can be used with any C/C++ compiler, and are often converted for use in other programming languages (Delphi, etc.).

A different division of Microsoft produces Visual Studio, with its own release cycle.  They package up the headers and libraries, but typically not the tools or samples, for the latest build of the Windows SDK available at the time Visual Studio is released.

Comment: Superset or subset of the last?

Comment: @Dialecticus - new SDKs contain all the APIs from previous versions.  Edited answer to be clear.